# set progress using Progressbar with just_audio flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

While working with just_audio, I need the progress of the audio and on the drag of the progress bar, I need to seek track to a particular position. I have referred to multiple answers but those were implemented with a third-party package.

So here is the implementation without any third-party package.

```
StreamBuilder<Duration?>(
    stream: _audioPlayer.durationStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final mediaDurationState = snapshot.data;
        return StreamBuilder<Duration?>(
            stream: _audioPlayer.positionStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                final mediaPositionState = snapshot.data;
                return ProgressBar(
                    total: mediaDurationState ?? const Duration(),
                    progress: mediaPositionState ?? const Duration(),
                    barHeight: 2,
                    baseBarColor: Colors.black,
                    progressBarColor: Colors.white,
                    thumbColor: Colors.white,
                    timeLabelTextStyle: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .bodyMedium
                        ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                    timeLabelLocation: TimeLabelLocation.sides,
                    onSeek: (newPosition) {
                        _audioPlayer.seek(newPosition);
                    },
                );
            },
        );
    }
),
```

Comment: This is my final implementation code in which the user can drag and seek that dragged position and duration and progress will also be set according to it.